# Compilation error: Null safety: Cannot call a nullable value

Tags: haxe

Today I tried to turn on strict nullSafety in my project, but I am constantly getting an error from the title during compilation: "Null safety: Cannot call a nullable value".

Am I doing something wrong or there is some kind of bug? Or maybe there are some workarounds?
Below is simplified code from my project:

```
class MyClass {
  private function validate(response: String): Void {
    trace('Validating: ${response}');
  }

  private function makeRequest(request: String, ?validator: String -> Void) {
    return function(response: String): Void {
      if (validator == null) {
        this.validate(request);
      } else {
        // as far as I understand, at this point `validator` should be considered as not null
        validator(request);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the latest Haxe version 4.1.2

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue locally, please provide a full [mcve] (including the definitions of `Response`, `Request` and `_makeRequest`)

Comment: @UnholySheep I am sorry I provided a wrong example. I've updated the code in my question. It seems that the error is happening if I am trying to return an anonymous function from `makeRequest`, which uses `validator` argument

Comment: I believe that is listed under Limitations (https://haxe.org/manual/cr-null-safety.html#limitations): *If a local variable is captured in a closure, it cannot be safe inside that closure*

Comment: Thank you! I missed that part of the documentation.